# NSIS uninstaller doesn't delete files/folders

Tags: nsis, delete-file

I'm writing a NSIS installer for one of the apps that the company I work for uses internally, the install process works fine, with no problems all the REG keys are created, and so are the files folders and services, that the App uses. For some reason I can't understand, the uninstall process doesn't work's.

The services created by the app are deleted and so are the Registry keys, the most simple part, the files themselves, I can't delete them through the uninstaller!

```
#Includes
!include "x64.nsh"
#Defines and Installer Properties
Outfile "ESTvnc Installer.exe"
Name ESTvnc 
Icon "${NSISDIR}\contrib\graphics\icons\VNCON.ico"
#Detect OS Version
Function .onInit
    StrCpy $instdir $PROGRAMFILES
    ${If} ${RunningX64}
        StrCpy $instdir $PROGRAMFILES32
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

section
    SetShellVarContext all  
    CreateDirectory $instdir\EST\ESTvnc
    setOutPath $instdir\EST\ESTvnc
    File /r installfiles\*
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ESTvnc\" \
                 "DisplayName" "ESTvnc"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ESTvnc"\
                 "UninstallString" "$instdir\EST\ESTvnc\uninstaller.exe"
    writeUninstaller $instdir\EST\ESTvnc\uninstaller.exe
    ExecWait '"$instdir\EST\estvnc\estvnc.exe" -install'
sectionEnd

section "Uninstall"
    SetShellVarContext all  
    SimpleSC::StopService "ESTVNC" 1 30
    pop $0
    SimpleSC::StopService "ESTVNCSR" 1 30
    pop $0
    SimpleSC::RemoveService "ESTVNC"
    SimpleSC::RemoveService "ESTVNCSR"    
    RMDir /r "$instdir\EST\ESTvnc"  
    Delete $instdir\EST\ESTvnc\uninstaller.exe  
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ESTvnc"  
sectionEnd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the uninstaller, `$instdir` is the directory the uninstaller is in!

Either place the uninstaller in `$instdir` and delete `$instdir\EST\ESTvnc` or if you want to keep it in `$instdir\EST\ESTvnc`, delete `$instdir`...